# Is it possible to compile the source with Clang using Clang C++ API in memory?

Tags: c++, ios, clang

I'd like to compile the sources using Clang with no executables running, but in-memory via API. I've found [post](http://fdiv.net/2012/08/15/compiling-code-clang-api) about how to do it but `Driver` seems to find and run executables like `clang`/`clang++` and `ld` behind the scene:

> The output shows that the Driver is invoking clang to do the compiling
>   and ld to do the linking. As you can see, the Driver adds arguments of
>   its own to each invocation, in addition to the ones we passed in. The
>   -v flag shows you exactly how the compiler and linker are being invoked.

As i'm going to do it on iOS running new process is prohibited (`fork` is prohibited) and paths are completely different.

So it there any way to compile the sources using Clang API with no executables running?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. It's how most OpenCL implementations work - they use the `clang` and `llvm` libraries to build a single executable (typically) that produces code for the hardware that CL runs on. I believe CUDA does something very similar, but I haven't studied it.

It's not terribly easy, but I guess I could have something up and running in a few days, maybe a couple of weeks worst case. I think the biggest problem will be the linking. In particular if you don't actually want to produce a executable file, but make an "in memory execution of the code" - which involves allocating memory that has execute rights, and then load the code, which is normally tasks that the linker and loader are responsible for.

Comment: it's okay to produce executable file, but in-memory execution would be great too. Any links are appreciated

Comment: Sorry, no links - I do however work with an OpenCL implementation, so I know it can be done, but it's also a lot more than what can be answered in a simple answer here at SO.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! Please let me know about your progress on it or update your answer later.